# What is the expected number of packets required to transmit $N$ bits?

Tags: probability, expectation

I am stuck on formulating this optimization problem and would appreciate your thoughts on this.

> A transmitter sends fixed data packet with $k$ bits of data. The cost of sending a data packet is $c$. I want to send $N$ bits of data. Each bit in the data packets has probability $p$ to be accepted or rejected. After each transmission I will know which bits have been successfully transmitted and accepted (and their locations too), and then I will re-transmit the remaining fragment of data bits in sequence again in another packet. What would be the expected number of packets for transmitting $N$ bits?

Any idea on how to model the problem? I am confused on whether this would be a case of a geometric distribution or beta distribution. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how the cost $c$ could enter into the result.

Comment: @joriki Of course the expected number of packets does not have anything to do with the cost c. It can be used to calculate the expected cost.

Comment: if you know the errors and their locations too, then why to bother to send them again? just flip the bits. You will only need $N$ transmissions! I think your problem is not formulated correctly.

Comment: @msm : bad transmission doesn't mean that datas had been received with the opposite values. they may be just not credible. Or else, it would be an implicit perfect protocol with no need of corrections

Comment: How do you define a bit being credible? when you send a bit 0 or 1 and it is received exactly the same, then how it could be not credible?